# ReferenceError: xepOnline is not defined when downloading PDF in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to download GoogleChart as `pdf` using jQuery and I use the code below.
When I run the code, it shows an error:

> ReferenceError: xepOnline is not defined

How can I download my PDF?

```
<!-- Convert the SVG to PDF and download it -->
var click="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('JSFiddle', {render:'download', srctype:'svg'})";
jQuery('#buttons').append('<button onclick="'+ click +'">PDF</button>');

<!-- Convert the SVG to PNG @ 120dpi and open it -->
click="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('JSFiddle', {render:'newwin', mimeType:'image/png', resolution:'120', srctype:'svg'})";
jQuery('#buttons').append('<button onclick="'+ click +'">PNG @120dpi</button>');

<!-- Convert the SVG to JPG @ 300dpi and open it -->
click="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('JSFiddle', {render:'newwin', mimeType:'image/jpg', resolution:'300', srctype:'svg'})";
jQuery('#buttons').append('<button onclick="'+ click +'">JPG @300dpi</button>');
```

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/zvx6eb7e/41/)

Comment: That is working fine, where/what is the issue? i don't get this not defined issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I used HighCharts.js export features I catched the 'xepOnline is not defined' error. 
The problem's source is missing [xepOnline.jqPlugin.js](http://www.cloudformatter.com) library.